# Add a table to a PDF template using iTextSharp and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I've been stuck on this far longer than I care to admit. I'm trying to use iTextSharp to build a table that I can then insert into a PDF template (which is really just a PDF with a header and an acrofield that needs to be populated). I've currently got code that follows the same outline below:

```
    Dim doc As New Document
    Dim reader As PdfReader
    Dim stamper As PdfStamper
    Dim filestream As FileStream
    Dim tempfile As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetTempFileName

    filestream = New FileStream(tempfile, FileMode.Create)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, filestream)
    doc.Open()
    generateTableForPdf(listOfData, numColumns, doc)
    doc.Close()

    reader = New PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath)
    stamper = New PdfStamper(reader, filestream)
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].headerField", "some text to go in the field")
```

The `pdfTemplatePath` is a private const that has the template's file path that I am trying to use and `generateTableForPdf` simply creates a dynamically sized table and puts it in `doc` (doc is passed by ref). I know the table is created because it displays when the page loads, however, the header in the template doesn't appear. I've looked around and found a couple of examples that use byte streams or memory streams, but my attempts at implementing those methods have failed more dramatically. Any help or guidance in better understanding how to go about this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].headerField" the name of the field in the PDF? I think perhaps you need to remove the double quotes - or hardcode an exact match to the PDF field name you are trying to populate.

Comment: `topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].headerField` is meant to be a field, but if you'd look inside the PDF, you'd see there's an error in the field name: there is no such thing as a field with name `topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].headerField`. Also: the name has the structure of an XFA field, so your form may contain XFA data. This makes the question very confusing: adding a table with repeating rows is a pure XFA thing; it's not something you'd do with AcroForms, yet reading the question, you're using AcroForm technology only. It's very hard to help somebody who doesn't know the basics...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - Which is the reason for me asking for help. This is only the second project I've worked on with PDFs. The first used nothing but AcroFields so it was relatively simple. However, apparently no one I work with has done something like this before, they have always had a template that followed the structure you described. Unfortunately, I am the guinea pig for figuring out how to place a dynamically created table on this "template."

Comment: @Captainn00b But you're like the guy on the phone asking: which color are my eyes. We can't tell the color of your eyes from the tone of your voice. Even so we can't tell you what the problem with your form is without seeing the form.